# How do I properly configure Spring OAuth 2 for Web UI log in?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have the OAuth 2 configuration working properly, and I'm currently in the process of enabling Web UI as well. Since the configuration involves Web security, I already have part of it set up. Actually, my understanding is that I don't really have much more to add anymore, other than the MVC components (like the login page, URL mappings, etc.) However, I'm having trouble logging into the Web app since the user is being tagged as `anonymousUser`.

Both `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` define method `configure(HttpSecurity)`. Currently, I'm using the one defined in `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` but that's where I'm experiencing the User being tagged as anonymous. If I try using the one in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (with OAuth 2 currently configured), I get the following error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer@546ed2a0 to already built object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
...
```

Caused by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer@546ed2a0 to already built object
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.add(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:196) ~[spring-security-config-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
...
```

However, when I disable everything related to the OAuth 2, and only use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (with `HttpSecurity` set up), login via the Web UI works as expected (i.e. user is not tagged as anonymous). I'm not sure what key area I got wrong on this.